RADUIS connectivity with Google Workspace
We have local RADIUS NPS with Wi-Fi authentication from Active Directory in Windows Server 2022.
The requirement is that only How RADIUS users can access Google Workspace emails without a third-party platform used between RADIUS and Workspace?
I have searched over google i didn't find solution
